# Slide accordion tab to browser top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I have a accordion menu with very lengthy content. So I need to implement slide effect when accordion content is opened up.

Currently if you open up the first two menu items then the last item shows up the content below the viewport so I need to have the slide up effect for the accordion menu items.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Accordion
    $(".menu_body").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class menu_body
    $(".menu_head").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".menu_body").slideToggle(400); 
        var plusmin;
        plusmin = $(this).children(".plusminus").text();

        $(this).children("span.down-arrow").toggleClass("up-arrow");        
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/orAKEVu/12)**

**Explanation:**

See there will be N number of accordion menu items with very long table data. And it should allow us to open multiple tabs open up.

Currently it is working fine but the problem is when u click on the menu item which is in the bottom of the page, it is showing up the content down so you wont be able to see it unless you scroll down manually.

This is why I need menu to auto slide scroll to the top of the browser so that content will be seen at a single glance.

Comment: If you're interested in jQuery UI, then take a look at this http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate the clicked button `offset` and scroll the whole page to that position 
minus some amount of pixels (100) just for beauty:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/irApUHUt/2/edit)**

```
$(function () {

    //Accordion
    $(".menu_body").hide();
    //toggle the componenet with class menu_body
    $(".menu_head").click(function(){
        var thisPOsTop = $(this).offset().top - 100;
        $(this).next(".menu_body").slideToggle(400); 
        var plusmin = $(this).find(".plusminus").text();        
        $(this).find("span.down-arrow").toggleClass("up-arrow");
      $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: thisPOsTop});
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/orAKEVu/14/edit)** which works fine.
code as below:

```
$(".menu_head").click(function(){

 $(this).next(".menu_body").slideToggle(400); 
    var plusmin;
    plusmin = $(this).children(".plusminus").text();

    $(this).children("span.down-arrow").toggleClass("up-arrow");

  var scrollvalue = $(this).offset().top;
  console.log(scrollvalue);
  setTimeout(function(){
  $(window).scrollTop( scrollvalue );
  },500);

});
```

Comment: I need multiple menu to be opened up so can not restrict for one at a time

Comment: what exactly you want to do? can you explain in detail?

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to auto scroll to the specific element? This 'method' could fire whenever you select an accordian element.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#elementtoScrollToID").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

The code above will complete the animation in 2 seconds (2000 ms), but you could change that to anything.

[This JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/orAKEVu/16/)  seems like exactly what you are looking for.

```
$('.menu_head').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop:$(this).offset().top }, 400);
});
```